# Cancelling a scheduled task via Chrono after a day

Tags: go, scheduled-tasks

I am exploring Go scheduler packages to run weekly/fortnightly jobs and this one, github.com/procyon-projects/chrono, seems to have good feedback. However, all examples apparently depict cancellation only by retaining handle to the scheduled task.

```
taskScheduler := chrono.NewDefaultTaskScheduler()

task, err := taskScheduler.ScheduleAtFixedRate(func(ctx context.Context) {
    log.Print("Fixed Rate of 5 seconds")
}, 5 * time.Second)

/* ... */
    
task.Cancel()
```

That is not feasible, we might have to restart services. Is there a way that an ID of the scheduled task is obtained which can then be persisted and used to cancel a scheduled weekly job, say after 4 days. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Scheduled tasks don't persist during restarts. When your process exits, so do the tasks running from your task scheduler.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not realise that, I was under the impression that these libraries would be using underlying cron framework to set up the scheduler.

Comment: I've never seen a library that does that, but such a library may exist.  Even so, the underlying cron scheduler doesn't track processes in that way, either.

Comment: Thanks, I will search more. I found this library that says it can persist across reboots but it does not seem to have a callback function when job is triggered, it seems to be using just a command. https://github.com/damdo/grontab